# Using TryGetComponent to return Child of <T>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, polymorphism

I am writing a component script for a Unity project using c#. I want to be able get a component or any inheriting child component from a gameobject. I have been using the following:

```
if(Buffets[index].TryGetComponent(out Fruit fruit))
{ 
    ... 
}
```

where `Buffets` is a `List<GameObject>` which has elements in it.

The problem I have is if the `GameObject` element has a `banana` component, which inherits from `fruit`, the `TryGetComponent` will return `false` and also not make fruit the banana.

I was wondering if there is a function or way to get any fruit children components this way. And examples would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're doing should work correctly as it is. TryGetComponent does work with inheritance. For example this (https://pastebin.com/DgCerKv9) will return true if you put a banana component on the gameobject. So the next thing to check would be whether you are in fact calling GetComponent on the gameobject that actually has the component you're looking for. Make sure that you're not referencing the wrong gameobject, that its not on a child gameobject,  etc.

Comment: You were right, the problem is elsewhere. Sorry for troubling you

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, though

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var fruit = Buffets[index].GetComponent<Fruit>()
// If fruit is not null
if (!fruit)
{

}
```

Comment: The problem was elsewhere. Thank you for your response, and sorry for troubling you.

Comment: Totally fine that's why this site is up :D, i was also wondering why `TryGetComponent` did not work the way u typed